# <rich:calendar> Locale.US (translate to czech)

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

is there any way to translate rich calendar to language which is not supported by Locale.XX ??

Thanks for help

**UPDATE:** part of my calendar bean

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name="calendarBean")
public class CalendarBean implements Serializable
{    
  /**/
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -219499296173801537L; 
  private Locale locale;    
  private String pattern;  
  private Date currentDate;  
  private Date selectedDate;  

  public Locale getLocale() {  
    return locale;  
  }  
  public void setLocale(Locale locale) {  
    this.locale = locale;  
  }  
  public String getPattern() {  
    return pattern;  
  }  
  public void setPattern(String pattern) {  
    this.pattern = pattern;  
  }  

  /* Constructor */
  public CalendarBean() {  
    locale = Locale.US;  
    pattern = "MMM d, yyyy";  
  }  

  public void selectLocale(ValueChangeEvent event) {  
    String tLocale = (String) event.getNewValue();  
    if (tLocale != null) 
    {  
      String lang = tLocale.substring(0, 2);  
      String country = tLocale.substring(3);  
      locale = new Locale(lang, country, "");  
    }  
  }  

  public Date getCurrentDate() {  
    return currentDate;  
  }  
  public void setCurrentDate(Date currentDate) {  
    this.currentDate = currentDate;  
  }  
  public Date getSelectedDate() {  
    return selectedDate;  
  }  
  public void setSelectedDate(Date selectedDate) {  
    this.selectedDate = selectedDate;  
  }  
}
```

UPDATE: (rich:calendar) with [EXAMPLE ON WEB](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar&skin=blueSky)

```
<rich:calendar mode="ajax" 
               boundaryDatesMode="scroll" 
               value="#{myBdeCheck.calendar.selectedDate}"  
               locale="#{calendarBean.locale}"  
               datePattern="#{calendarBean.pattern}"                        
               cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" style="width:200px"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, locales are not limited. Just use the constructor `new Locale("your language")`

For the calendar - it has a property for each i18nable thing, so you can use your `#{msg.foo}` there:

The [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_calendar.html) writes:

> The  component allows to use "header" , "footer" , "optionalHeader" , "optionalFooter" facets. The following elements are available in these facets: {currentMonthControl}, {nextMonthControl}, {nextYearControl}, {previousYearControl}, {previousMonthControl}, {todayControl}, {selectedDateControl}. These elements could be used for labels output.

Comment: Thank you, Bozho. But I'm not sure how, i'm begginer in JAVA :)

Comment: nothing, locale.US works very fine, but I need calendar interface translated to czech language :)

Comment: do you have messages_cz.properties?

Comment: where? And what happens when you use the chech locale?

Comment: Oops, it seems we are talking about different things. I haven't problem with ASCII, I don´t know how to translate english named days or months to czech. For example "tuesday" is "utery" and "january" is "leden"..?

Comment: That is the problem, I don't know, it is the richfaces component :]

Comment: add a breakpoint and see what is the locale when you open the page. Also try new `Locale("cz")` (without the other arguments)

Comment: Yes, viz updated original post. But I don't know anything more about the calendar

Comment: I didn´t understand you, but you were right! (SOLUTION: calendar bean: locale = new java.util.Locale("cs","CZ"); xhtml: <rich:calendar locale="#{calendarBean.locale}">). Thank you, Bozho!!!